# Subshells and PIDs: Why do $$ and \$\$ sometimes match under nested sh -c?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I know this is an artificially complicated example, but why are both PIDs the same in the first line, while (as expected, to me at least) the two other lines yield different PIDs?

```
$ sh -c 'sh -c "echo $$ \$\$"'
4500 4500
$ sh -c 'sh -c "echo $$ \$\$"; true'
4596 5060
$ sh -c 'true; sh -c "echo $$ \$\$"'
4728 2868
```

Thanks!

Comment: What OS and what shell are you using?

Comment: Sorry for the undue confusion... I'm using Cygwin, but this happens both under bash and ash. Disappointing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me in bash 4.1.5, the output of first line is:

```
sh -c 'sh -c "echo $$ \$\$"'
4063 4064
```

as expected - values are different.
Also tested on ash, sh, and zsh.

It must be some tricky optimization.

**Update:**

in bash 3.2 there is and "ONESHOT" feature:
see comment in the [shell.c:1243](http://www.google.com/codesearch#p9nGS4eQGUI/pub/gnu/bash/bash-3.2.tar.gz%7CgkmC4yQMM8E/bash-3.2/shell.c&exact_package=ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/bash/bash-3.2.tar.gz&q=getopt%20package%3abash&l=1243):

```
#if defined (ONESHOT)
/* Run one command, given as the argument to the -c option.  Tell
parse_and_execute not to fork for a simple command. */
```

Comment: I'm seeing what the OP is seeing using bash 3.2.48(1). I agree that this is likely an optimization where the `echo` either is or is not forked depending on whether there is multiple commands.

Comment: Rob, are you also using Cygwin?